# Why is my floated span tags are bigger rather than how much size of its content is?

Tags: html, css

I have three span tags, First two span tags are floated left and floated right respectively.

But the floated span tags got bigger than its content size.

I need the floated span tags sizes like the third span tag, like only the size of its content.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<div>
<span class="a">ddd</span>
<span class="b">abc</span>
</div>
<br/>
<span class="c">fff</span>
<style>
div{
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
width:100%;
}
.a{
float: left
}
.b{
float: right;
}
.b,.a,.c{
background: red;
}
</style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is only the size of its content. The span wraps around the text content, but the text content of a and b is high because you set a high line-height. Even though there are no pixels of letter in that space, it doesn't mean it's not part of the line. After all, you also wouldn't expect a line that contains only `-----` to be less high than a line containing `llllllllllll`.

Answer (score 0):

Your spans `a` and `b` are contained inside a `div` element to which you have specified a `line-height`. Span `c` is outside of this `div` and therefore does not have this extra space around it.

If you want all spans to be like `c`, remove the `line-height` declarations from `div`

```
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first two `span`'s are in a `div` with [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) set.

`span`'s are [`inline elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements).

They end up as high as the line they're in.

Remove the `line-height`, and you're good to go.

Comment: Okay if i remove the line height how can i align the span tag in center of the div tag (I mean vertically)?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to do, is the height of the `div` always fixed? Like in your example?